# How to convert UTF-8 to ANSI csv file

Tags: php, csv, encode

I'm actually generating csv files in php, works great but I have to use these csv files to use into Microsoft Dynamics AX and here's the problem.
Csv file that I generated gets "NUL" space on some columns and I have to pull off those spaces to get clean csv files and use it in Dynamics AX.
I saw when opening them into Notepad ++ that csv files are in UTF-8 BOM and I want to convert them to ANSI, when I make the conversion to ANSI in Notepad++, all NUL spaces disappear.
I tried different things saw on StackOverflow and it is with the **iconv** method that I obtained the better result but it is far from perfect and what I expect.

Here's the actual code :

```
fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));
                for ( $a = 0 ; $a < count($tableau) ; $a++ ) {
                    foreach ( $tableau[$a] as $data ) {
                        fputcsv($fp, $data, ";", chr(0));
                    }
                }
                $fp=iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $fp);
                fclose($fp);
                echo json_encode(responseAjax(true));
            }
```

and I obtain these result :
[image]

I don't understand why it's only apply in one cell instead on working on every cells which contain "NUL" spaces.
I tried the mb_converting_encoding method with no great result.
Any other idea, method or advice will be welcome,
thanks

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the thing is that I'm new to convert files into Csv and the "original" code is not from me so there are some "details" that were not so explicit to me. I understand better now. I changed `chr(0)` to `chr(32)` and I have a real whitespace instead of the 'NUL' symbol which is better but still an issue. I tried to remove the whitespace with **trim** or **str_replace** methods but space stills here. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

"NUL" is the name generally given to a binary value of `00000000`, which has the same meaning in all ASCII-compatible encodings, which includes UTF-8, Windows-1252, and most things that could be given the vague label "ANSI". So character encoding is not relevant here.

You appear to be explicitly adding it with `chr(0)` - specifically as the "enclosure" argument to [fputcsv](https://php.net/fputcsv), so it's being used in place of quote marks around strings with spaces or punctuation. The string "Avion" doesn't need enclosing, which is why it doesn't have any NULs around.

Let's add some comments to the code you've apparently copied without understanding:

```
// Output the three bytes known as the "UTF-8 BOM"
// - an invisible character used to help software guess that a file should be read as UTF-8
fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF));
// Loop over the data
for ( $a = 0 ; $a < count($tableau) ; $a++ ) {
    foreach ( $tableau[$a] as $data ) {
        // Output a row of CSV data with the built-in function fputcsv
        // $data is the array of data you want to output on this row
        // Use ';' as the separator between columns
        // Use chr(0) - a NUL byte - to "enclose" fields with spaces or punctuation
        // The default would be to use comma (',') and quotes ('"')
        // See the PHP manual at https://php.net/fputcsv for more details
        fputcsv($fp, $data, ";", chr(0));
    }
}
```

---

The character you use for the "enclosure" is entirely up to you; most systems will probably expect the default `"`, so you could use this:

```
fputcsv($fp, $data, ";");
```

Which is the same as this:

```
fputcsv($fp, $data, ";", '"');
```

The function doesn't support disabling the enclosure completely, but without it, CSV is fundamentally a very simple format - just combine the fields separated by some character, e.g. using [implode](https://php.net/implode):

```
fwrite($fp, implode(";", $data));
```

---

Character encoding is a completely separate issue. For that, you need to know *two* things:

- What encoding is your data in
- What encoding does the remote system want it in

If these don't match, you can use a function like `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding`.

If your output is *not* UTF-8, you should also remove the line at the beginning of your code that outputs the UTF-8 BOM.

If your data is stored in UTF-8, and the remote system accepts data in UTF-8, you don't need to do anything here.